# python return ydata from matplotlib click

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to click on a plot from matplotlib and return the y value of the location of the click to a variable. I have used the example from matplotlib, which prints out the location from event.ydata, but cannot figure out how to return it!

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

def onclick(event):
    print 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f'%(event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

Comment: What are you trying to return it to?  If you just want to record the location for other code to use, you could use a global variable and assign event.ydata to it in the callback.

Comment: I wanted to return it to a non-global variable, but in the scope of this script, not within the onclick function (ie like cid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to pop up a plot and wait for the user to click on a point in it before continuing.  As far as I know there is no pre-packaged way of doing this, but the code below should do what you want.  Full disclosure: It does use a global variable.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

retval = -1
def onclick(event):
    print 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f'%(event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)
    # Record the x location of the user's click in the global variable and close the figure
    global retval
    retval = event.xdata
    plt.close()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
# Bring up the figure (and wait)
plt.show()

print 'User selected point {0}'.format( retval )
```